# How do I retrieve the ID of a related record in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a custom object whose fields I want to display in an LWC under a tab on the Account Record page. I need criteria to query that related record, I only need one record stored and it's rare that there are multiple records matching the criteria. I also want to navigate from the LWC to the related record through a button.

I am unable to figure out how to query the related record and get its ID for the navigation button and pass it in HTML to display fields. That's the (hopefully) only thing I need help with.

Here's my JS code:

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';

export default class CmpAccSCRecDisplay extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)
{
        @api recordId;
        error;
        record;  
        @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
            parentRecordId: this.recordId,
            relatedListId: 'Software_Assets__c',
            fields: ['Software_Assets__c.Id']
        })listInfo({ error, data }) {
            if (data) {
                this.record = data.record;
                this.error = undefined;
            } else if (error) {
                this.error = error;
                this.record = undefined;
            }
        }    
        handleSCClick()
        {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: this.data.record.recordId,
                    objectApiName: 'Software_Assets__c',
                    actionName: 'view',
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to pass '$recordId' in wire then inside data you have to put forEach loop and filter your records as you require. In navigation "this.data.record.Id" is not available you have to store it in variable then use in navigation